# Merging text files

Tags: merge, text-files, disk, low-level

I want to merge many text files to a file.
But the normal solutions ( like copy in command prompt or using c# in streaming way ) is not good for me because they are very slow and uses huge amount of system IO.
Is there any way with a low level programing that merge this files without loading in the memory? for example just with new addressing in the disk.
I believe windows defragmentation uses this method for moving block of a file.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting.  This sounds possible in theory, but I don't think there are any system calls to move a block or extent from one file to another.  (At least not on Linux.  I assume Windows doesn't have this either.)  It would of course create a fragmented file, but if the extents are large that's not a big deal.  (e.g. fragments or two per GB).

Comment: Some filesystems could even support multiple files having some data in common, without being hard-links.  (e.g. copy-on-write filesystems like ZFS or BTRFS).  In that case, you could in theory combine files into a merged file without deleting the originals.